# Iterate on a date column from one dataframe and check if there is a record present for these dates in another dataframe;using R

Tags: r

**Update 1 -**
I have 2 dataframes, the first one has the following columns

| Person ID | Event ID | Event Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ABC | 04-11-2020 |
| 1234 | BCD | 15-09-2020 |
| 1234 | DEF | 18-06-2020 |

*I need to add one more column called Flag to it*

and the second one has the following columns (there can be more than 2 rows per person id in the second dataframe)

| Person ID | Date | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 04-10-2020 | 1 |
| 1234 | 02-11-2020 | 2 |
| 1234 | 09-02-2021 | 1 |

Resultant Table -

| Person ID | Event ID | Event Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ABC | 04-11-2020 | 1 |

> In this example, there are 2 records which are 90 days before the
> event, we shall consider the level of the latest one i.e. 02-11-2020
> Therefore, the Level for the Person 1234, Event ABC & Event Date -
> 04-11-2020 is changing from 2 to 1, the flag value for the first row
> of the first dataframe would be 1.

Now, I need to pick the first Event Date from the first dataframe and check if there is a record present for this Event date in the second dataframe. I am interested in getting 2 kinds of records from dataframe 2 -

1. Date which is 0 to 90 days before the Event Date &
2. Date which is 0 to 90 days after the Event Date

Once I have both these records, I need to compare the change in the level. I need to get a flag in the first dataframe. 1 if there is a change in level, 0 if there is no change.

**Changes -**

1. Added a resultant table, explained the same through an example
2. Elaborated on the 90 days before and after date(s) meaning

Comment: How about just merging the data frames and then you can compare the dates and whatever you want to do

Comment: I could not understand! what is meant by 90 days before/after.  What if there are multiple dates matching this criteria in DF2? Whether there can be more than two dates per person in DF2?  I think you need to elaborate your example to include all the possibilities? Or please rule out these possibilities.  How do you detect change in level?  Do you mean event date falling in between two dates mentioned?

Comment: Still I am not clear.  Why you considered it as a level change when the level was changed on 9-2-21 i.e. more than 90 days later than event date i.e. 4-11-20? Actually 93 days later

Comment: Please also add an example of flag 0, your question may become clear then!